# Fit a piecewise regression in matlab and find change point

Tags: matlab

In matlab, I want to fit a piecewise regression and find where on the x-axis the first change-point occurs. For example, for the following data, the output might be `changepoint=20` (I don't actually want to plot it, just want the change point).

```
data = [1 4 4 3 4 0 0 4 5 4 5 2 5 10 5 1 4 15 4 9 11 16 23 25 24 17 31 42 35 45 49 54 74 69 63 46 35 31 27 15 10 5 10 4 2 4 2 2 3 5 2 2];
x = 1:52;
plot(x,data,'.')
```

Comment: Do you have the Signal Processing Toolbox? If you do, you can do this in just one line of code using `findchangepts`.

Comment: omg that's amazing @edwinksl thanks so much! You should write the answer so I can give you the bounty :)

Comment: Sounds good, I just wrote an answer and added some minor details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Signal Processing Toolbox, you can directly use the `findchangepts` function (see https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findchangepts.html for documentation):

```
data = [1 4 4 3 4 0 0 4 5 4 5 2 5 10 5 1 4 15 4 9 11 16 23 25 24 17 31 42 35 45 49 54 74 69 63 46 35 31 27 15 10 5 10 4 2 4 2 2 3 5 2 2];
x = 1:52;
ipt = findchangepts(data);
x_cp = x(ipt);
data_cp = data(ipt);

plot(x,data,'.',x_cp,data_cp,'o')
```

The index of the change point in this case is 22.

Plot of data and its change point circled in red:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is cool. I have to wait 22 hours to award the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but just want to provide some extra thoughts. In Maltab, an alternative implemented by me is a Bayesian changepoint detection algorithm that estimates not just the number and locations of the changepoints but also reports the occurrence probability of changepoints. In its current implementation, it deals with only time-series-like data (aka, 1D sequential data). More info about the tool is available at this FileExchange entry (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72515-bayesian-changepoint-detection-time-series-decomposition).

Here is its quick application to your sample data:

```
% Automatically install the Rbeast or BEAST library to local drive
eval(webread('http://b.link/rbeast')) %

data = [1 4 4 3 4 0 0 4 5 4 5 2 5 10 5 1 4 15 4 9 11 16 23 25 24 17 31 42 35 45 49 54 74 69 63 46 35 31 27 15 10 5 10 4 2 4 2 2 3 5 2 2];

out = beast(data, 'season','none') % season='none': there is no seasonal/periodic variation in the data
printbeast(out)
plotbeast(out)
```

Below is a summary of the changepoint, given by printbeast():

```
#####################################################################
#                      Trend  Changepoints                          #
#####################################################################
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
| Ascii plot of probability distribution for number of chgpts (ncp) |
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
|Pr(ncp = 0 )=0.000|*                                               |
|Pr(ncp = 1 )=0.000|*                                               |
|Pr(ncp = 2 )=0.000|*                                               |
|Pr(ncp = 3 )=0.859|*********************************************** |
|Pr(ncp = 4 )=0.133|********                                        |
|Pr(ncp = 5 )=0.008|*                                               |
|Pr(ncp = 6 )=0.000|*                                               |
|Pr(ncp = 7 )=0.000|*                                               |
|Pr(ncp = 8 )=0.000|*                                               |
|Pr(ncp = 9 )=0.000|*                                               |
|Pr(ncp = 10)=0.000|*                                               |
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
|    Summary for number of Trend ChangePoints (tcp)                 |
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
|ncp_max    = 10   | MaxTrendKnotNum: A parameter you set           |
|ncp_mode   = 3    | Pr(ncp= 3)=0.86: There is a 85.9% probability  |
|                  | that the trend component has  3 changepoint(s).|
|ncp_mean   = 3.15 | Sum{ncp*Pr(ncp)} for ncp = 0,...,10            |
|ncp_pct10  = 3.00 | 10% percentile for number of changepoints      |
|ncp_median = 3.00 | 50% percentile: Median number of changepoints  |
|ncp_pct90  = 4.00 | 90% percentile for number of changepoints      |
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
| List of probable trend changepoints ranked by probability of      |
| occurrence: Please combine the ncp reported above to determine    |
| which changepoints below are  practically meaningful              |
'-------------------------------------------------------------------'
|tcp#              |time (cp)                  |prob(cpPr)          |
|------------------|---------------------------|--------------------|
|1                 |33.000000                  |1.00000             |
|2                 |42.000000                  |0.98271             |
|3                 |19.000000                  |0.69183             |
|4                 |26.000000                  |0.03950             |
|5                 |11.000000                  |0.02292             |
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
```

Here is the graphic output. Three major changepoints are detected (i.e., vertical lines). As a Bayesian method, it tells not just whether there are any changepoints but also the probability of changepoint occurrence as in the `Pr(tcp)` subplot where the peaks correspond to the detected changepoints.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use sgolayfilt function, that is a polynomial fit to the data, or reproduce OLS method: http://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-LeastSquares06-pretty.pdf (there is *a+bx* notation instead of *ax+b*)

For linear fit of *ax+b*:

If you replace x with constant vector of length 2n+1: [-n, ... 0 ... n] on each step, you get the following code for sliding regression coeffs:

```
for i=1+n:length(y)-n
    yi = y(i-n : i+n); 
    sum_xy = sum(yi.*x);

    a(i) = sum_xy/sum_x2;
    b(i) = sum(yi)/n;
end
```

Notice that in this code **b** means sliding average of your data, and **a** is a least-square slope estimate (first derivate).

Comment: thanks for this suggestion - are you able to provide an example of how to apply this to my `data` in the above example?

Comment: Just put this code into matlab fuction of (y, n) and return a, b values (y stands for your data).

Comment: n stands for window length / 2. Also, sum_x2 = sum(x.^2).

Comment: thanks for your help with this - I'm not very experienced with matlab so would you mind clarifying what 'window' means? Is it length of x? Also, what is my output here? I'm looking for a number likely ~21 for this example.